# Como fazer para buscar arquivos atraves de nomes

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angularjs

Estou tentando fazer uma busca através de nomes, em uma pasta contendo vários arquivos JSON diferentes .

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http){

    $scope.buscar = function(name){
        $scope.search = name;
        $scope.lista = $scope.pesquisa;
        if(name != null){
            $http.get("http://10.10.6.22/json").success(function(data)
         {
            $scope.pesquisa = data;
         });
            return $scope.lista = {};
        }
    else{
      return "O Nome nao existente";
        }
    }
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lattes.css"/>

        <title>Lattes</title>

    </head>

    <body ng-controller="customersCtrl">

        <h1>Buscador lattes</h1>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" id="teste">
                <!--Com botão-->
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search"class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
                <button type="submit" ng-click="buscar(name)" class="btn btn-success">
                    <i classe="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>

    <!--Sem botão-->
    <!-- <input type="text" ng-model="data"ng-keyup="procurar(data)"> -->


        <!--CCM-->
        <div id="name">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <!-- <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th>Artigo</th>
                        <th>Qualis</th>
                        <th>Evento</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead> -->
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in lista | filter: search">
                    <td>{{x.ano}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.artigo}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.qualis}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.evento}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <!--CCM-->

    </body>
    <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
</html>
```

---

Não funcionou, ai tentei desta forma mais não vai, ou quando vai, so me retorna 1 das minha duas opções.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http){
        $http.get("http://10.10.6.22/json/MarcosdeCastro.php").success(function(data){
                $scope.pesquisa = data;
            $scope.nome = "Marcos de Castro";
            $scope.buscar = function(name){
            $scope.search = name;
            $scope.lista = $scope.pesquisa;
            if((name && nome)=='Marcos de Castro'){
            $scope.lista = {};
            }
        }
    });
            $http.get("http://10.10.6.22/json/MauroHenrique.php").success(function(data){
                $scope.pesquisa = data;

            $scope.nome = "Mauro Henrique";
            $scope.buscar = function(name){
            $scope.search = name;
            $scope.lista = $scope.pesquisa;
            if((name && nome)=='Mauro Henrique'){
            $scope.lista = {};
            }
        }
    }); 

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lattes.css"/>

        <title>Lattes</title>

    </head>

    <body ng-controller="customersCtrl">

        <h1>Buscador lattes</h1>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" id="teste">
                <!--Com bot�o-->
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search"class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
                <button type="submit" ng-click="buscar(search)" class="btn btn-success">search
                    <i classe="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>

    <!--Sem bot�o-->
    <!-- <input type="text" ng-model="data"ng-keyup="procurar(data)"> -->


        <!--CCM-->
        <div id="name">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <!-- <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th>Artigo</th>
                        <th>Qualis</th>
                        <th>Evento</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead> -->
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in lista | filter: search">
                    <td>{{x.ano}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.artigo}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.qualis}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.evento}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <!--CCM-->

    </body>
    <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual é a sua pergunta exatamente? Algo não está funcionando? Há alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Não tem resposta, na hora busca.
Por exemplo, eu sei que dentro do diretório json tem um arquivo chamado mauro.json, mais quando eu busco através do nome Mauro ele nao retorna nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando para o seu código, e partindo do prencipio que esse é todo o código,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search"class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
```

O ng-model do `input` tem o valor `search`, no entanto no butão

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="buscar(name)" class="btn btn-success">
```

Você usa `name`.

Depois, no seu javascript

```
$scope.buscar = function(name){
    $scope.search = name;
    $scope.lista = $scope.pesquisa;
```

Você usa `name`, que nunca foi defenido em algum lado, e troca o valor ao `ng-model` do `input` para ser igual a um parametro que não tem valor.

Se você usar

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="buscar(search)" class="btn btn-success">
```

e no Javascript

```
$scope.buscar = function(name){
    //$scope.search = name;
    $scope.lista = $scope.pesquisa;
    if(name != null){
```

(repare na linha comentada) é muito provavel que o código faça o que você quer.